# Can Ifill the blank cell table in google docs with the data from google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a formed table in google docs.
I want to fill the blank of table in google docs with the data from google sheet.
Is this possible?

*I've tried several advices but all of them was just to extract data from sheet to google docs as a whole, not to fill the blank of pre-set table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand what  you are asking but here's a easy way to fill a 2 dimensional array of cells in a spreadsheet,  r is the row of the origin and c is the column and a is the 2 dimensional array of data

Here's the function using default parameters:

```
function filltable(r=5,c=5,a=[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30]]) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh.getRange(r,c,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

Here's what the output looks like:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 |  |  |  |  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 8 |  |  |  |  | 15 | 16 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 9 |  |  |  |  | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 10 |  |  |  |  | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i think i didn't clarify my question above. For example, in your example data sheet, if i made same table with the same row and column number in 'google docs', can i extract those data from sheet to docs automatically?

Comment: Yes.............